# Phase angle between two sinsoidal currents

Tags: phase-shift

I am having trouble solving an example in the book I came up with another solution, anyway the question asked to find the phase angle between two give currents- see attached image what I did I converted the I1 to cos by 90 it became 4cos(377t+145) and I drew both angles as attached image 2 . And I got that I2 leads I1 by 150.

The book's answer is different than mine is the book mistaken

[image: the question and the book's ans]

[image: my answer]

Comment: The question is "does i1 lead or lag i2?" Your answer is correct, but not the answer to the question asked.

Comment: Why not? I mentioned that I2 leads i1 by 150 deg (phase angle) but the book mentioned the opposite i1 leads i2 by 210 deg @PhilG

Comment: Surely they are both correct, they are the same angle as 150+210 = 360. I would think in normal nomenclature you would not use values above 180 degrees so the 150 would be the correct answer.

Comment: But the book said i1 leads my answer is i2 leads @KevinWhite

Comment: Current equations aside, I believe this is more of a mathematical question. I can prove mathematically if \$i_1\$ or leads \$i_2\$, this is a basic trigonometry question.

Comment: Could you please do it .. it will be appreciated if you could

Comment: \$-sin(\theta +55)=cos(\theta +55+90)=cos(\theta +145)\$, hence phase difference is \$145^o-(-65^o)=210^o\$. \$i_1\$ leads \$i_2\$

Comment: @Chu but why i1 leads see my graph I drew the two angles

Comment: Your statement that " i2 leads i1 by 150 deg" could be inverted to state " i1 lags i2 by 150 deg", which is to my thinking the correct answer to the question as asked, since, as @KevinWhite says, you typically don't quote angles above 180, but lagging by 150 is identical to leading by 210.

Comment: Your graph shows i1 leads i2 by 210 degrees. Leading phase is anticlockwise. To rotate from i2 to i1 you go through 210 degrees.

Comment: Your answer is correct. The book is wrong. The angle between two vectors is always the smallest angle between then. Then, 210 degrees can't be the right answer here.